# How to hide implemented delegate method from other class depending on BOOL value? - objecitve c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to hide implemented method of my custom `delegate` in `UIViewController` class, depending on `BOOL` property "isHidden". I call one `UIViewController` from 2 places, and I need to hide delegate method from one of these classes. For example Class A and B call my `UIViewController` and check this method with `respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)`, and if `BOOL` property is `TRUE`, so let `respondsToSelector` method return `TRUE` value, else - `FALSE`. Is this possible?

Comment: You can override `-(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel` and play there with some of your flags, you can compare selectors with `sel_isEqual` (`objc/runtime.h`), ... But it's weird and not recommended solution. Why do you want to do it in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the delegate call these methods.. and depending on the bool value perform the task in them or just let it pass...

Answer (score 1):

Well… It's possible to swap selectors' implementations via the runtime (e.g. to an implementation which does nothing), but it's a terrible solution. And that affects all instances -- this approach makes a singleton look like gold.

Instead, consider something like introducing the condition to `myMethod`, so myMethod just does nothing dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern where you define the delegate method as following:

```
@protocol MyObjectDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)myObject:(id)myObject processSomeData:(id)someData;

@end
```

So your delegate controller knows which object requests this method and can decide what to do.
In addition you can add some method like this to notify the object if it has rights to access this method before it actually sends a message

```
- (BOOL)myObjectCanProcessSomeData:(id)myObject;
```

Of course there are some technics to add and remove object methods by interacting with the Objective-C Runtime, but I am not sure if this is a great idea.